# Display another list of options if one option is selected

Tags: html, html-select

What I want is when a user selects an option in the list between the "select" tags a new list will appear on the right side of the first list.

An example of my code at the moment:

```
<label for="example>Example</label>
<select id="example_list" type="text" name="example_list">
    <option value="choose">Choose..</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Here's a simple image of what I want.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a contextual menu. You can achieve that by making a CSS dropdown menu. A simple google search for "css dropdown tutorial" would yield lots of valuable search results which would point you in the direction of what you want.

Comment: @BeNdErR I've only searched on stackoverflow and just on Google but could'nt find anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @Gagan I will edit my post and add the code I have at the moment. But I think it doesn't help solve my answer because it is almost nothing.

Comment: It is call Vertical Menu Option..

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting sounds like a strange thing to do, and at the very least, what you're describing is not readily achievable in HTML.

The closest thing I can think of with HTML, if you only need two levels, is the `<optgroup>` tag, which allows you to group options:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Option 1">
        <option>Option 1.1</option>
        <option>Option 1.2</option>
        <option>Option 1.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option 2">
        <option>Option 2.1</option>
        <option>Option 2.2</option>
        <option>Option 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Which will result in the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/E3WZ4/

[image: optgroup tag]

---

If that doesn't suit your needs, I agree with the comment left by @Maritim, you might not want a `<select>` at all, and instead opt for a dropdown menu, something like http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/

Comment: But how do I make it work just like a selector then?

Comment: @user3706620 That code *is* a standard `<select>`, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As you had mentioned in image that new list will appear on the right side of the first list.
Here is a code using `<ul>` and `<li>` tag using pure `CSS`:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Parent 1</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 1.1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 1.2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>child 1.3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Parent 2</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 2.1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 2.2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>child 2.3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Parent 3</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 3.1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>child 3.2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>child 3.3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/VCX7T/328/)**.
If it satisfied your requirement then up vote my ans. Thank you..

Comment: Just what xec told me on the end of his answer, but how do I make it work like a selector? I'm using it for a form by the way if that is necessary. And it doesn't work really that good, xec told you already.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the `select` menus joined the way you have drawn, because the moment the user clicks an `option` in the first `select`, the options drop-down retracts, leaving nothing but the one-row `select` with the clicked `option` visible in it. And if you want a hover (mouseover) calling of the sub menus, you should simply use a multi-level CSS menu constructed with lists, not selects.

For a tutorial on how to make such a CSS menu without any javascript (including jQuery), [see here](http://www.conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/how-to-make-a-menu-with-css.php). There is a tiny bit of javascript in that tutorial, but that is just to cater to IE6, which is long dead. (The tut should be modernized in that respect.)

That tutorial also has the code to cater to touchscreens, on which one cannot hover.